# Got a block with a timecode before the previous block

Tags: javascript, html5-video, media-source

I'm trying to append a chunk to a sourceBuffer, after downloading the first chunk i simply use `sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buf);` but a `Got a block with a timecode before the previous block.` error happen and the chunk is not appended.

I've been searching all over the internet for a week now, I didn't find anything to help at all !

```
 var videoNumber = 1;
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var assetURL = '/classes/'+class_id+'/video/';
var segmentDuration = 5;
var duration = 5 ;
var videoRequesterInterval;
// var videoRequestTimer = 0;
// Need to be specific for Blink regarding codecs
// ./mp4info frag_bunny.mp4 | grep Codec
var mimeCodec = 'video/webm; codecs="vp8, opus"';
var sourceBuffer;

var mediaSource;

if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
    mediaSource = new MediaSource;


    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
} else {
    console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
}

/**
 * @desc start when video opened
 * @param _
 */
function sourceOpen (_) {
    console.log("source opened");
    //console.log(this.readyState); // open
    sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
    appendSegmentIfExist();
    // video.addEventListener('timeupdate', checkBuffer);
    sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', playVideo);
    sourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', logError);

}

var tries = 0;
function fetchVideo(videoNumber,callback = function (response) {

}) {
    console.log("fetch video number "+ videoNumber);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('get', assetURL+videoNumber);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onloadend = function() {
        if(xhr.status === 404)
        {
            console.log('tries is '+ tries);
            if(tries > 3)
            {
                mediaSource.endOfStream();
                clearInterval(videoRequesterInterval);
                return;
            }
            tries++;
            fetchVideo(videoNumber,callback);
        }
        else
        {
            tries++;
            callback(xhr.response);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

function appendSegment() {
    fetchVideo(videoNumber,function(buf)
    {
        if(videoEl.currentTime === 0)
        {
            video.play();
            videoRequesterInterval = setInterval(function(){
                videoNumber++;
                appendSegment();
                }, (segmentDuration)*1000);
        }

        console.log(buf);

        sourceBuffer.timestampOffset = duration - segmentDuration;
        duration += 5;
        sourceBuffer.appendWindowStart = 0;
        // sourceBuffer.appendWindowEnd = 5;
        // console.log(sourceBuffer);
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buf);
        console.log(sourceBuffer);
    });
}

function appendSegmentIfExist()
{
    console.log("check if there is video on server ");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('get', assetURL+videoNumber);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onloadend = function() {
        if(xhr.status === 404)
        {
            console.log('no video on server ');
        }
        else
        {
            appendSegment();
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

function playVideo() {
    console.log('update end');
    console.log(sourceBuffer.buffered);
    console.log(mediaSource.readyState);
    // mediaSource.duration = Infinity;
    console.log(mediaSource.duration);
}

function logError(e) {
    console.log("-----------");
    console.log(e);
    console.log(sourceBuffer);
    console.log(video.error.message);
}
```

Edit:
Ok, After a really long trace I've noticed some strange things:
1- the issue only appear if you record the media in Firefox then added to sourceBuffer in chrome browser, the error will not happen if you record the media using chrome.

2- the array buffer have negative values

```
    [[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(916168) [26, 69, -33, -93, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 66, -122, -127, 1, 66, -9, -127, 1, 66, -14, -127, 4, 66, -13, -127, 8, 66, -126, -124, 119, 101, 98, 109, 66, -121, -127, 2, 66, -123, -127, 2, 24, 83, -128, 103, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 17, 77, -101, 116, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 73, -87, 102, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 73, 42, -41, -79, -125, 15, 66, 64, 68, -119, -120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 77, -128, -104, …]
[[Int16Array]]: Int16Array(458084) [17690, -23585, 1, 0, 0, 7936, -31166, 385, -2238, 385, -3518, 1153, -3262, 2177, -32190, 30596, 25189, 17005, -32377, 16898, -32379, 6146, -32685, 359, -1, -1, -1, 4607, -25779, 372, 0, 0, 0, 5376, -22199, 358, 0, 0, 0, 10825, -20009, 3971, 16450, -30396, 136, 0, 0, 0, 19712, -26496, 21585, 30061, 27000, 26478, 28737, 19568, 25193, 25943, 19810, 12333, 12334, 12590, 16727, 20889, 30548, 26994, 26996, 26478, 28737, 19568, 25193, 25943, 19810, 12333, 12334, 12590, 21526, 27566, 1, 0, 0, -27392, 430, 0, 0, 0, -10452, 385, -14989, 25732, -32305, 9507, -30586, 22147, 14416, -32381, -31231, 22149, 22111, 14416, …]
[[Int32Array]]: Int32Array(229042) [-1545648870, 1, 520093696, 25265730, 25294658, 75625026, 142734146, 2005172802, 1114464869, 1107460487, 402817413, 23560275, -1, 301989887, 24419149, 0, 352321536, 23505225, 0, 709427200, 260288983, -1992015806, 136, 0, -1736422144, 1970099281, 1735289208, 1282437185, 1700225641, 808275298, 825110574, 1368998231, 1769109332, 1735289204, 1282437185, 1700225641, 808275298, 825110574, 1806586902, 1, -1795162112, 430, 0, 25286444, 1686422899, 623083983, 1451460742, -2122106800, 1451591169, 944789087, 480, 0, 42119176, 25344640, 110304, 0, -2116593920, -2067434750, 565692838, 1443004803, 1660978346, -1151950802, -1262222204, 1099335168, 1431326559, -1818074285, 1937076303, 1684104520, 20447489, 44100, 620756992, 1334085766, -514632368, 1, 218103808, -448755531, 32904, -2120286208, -1237115135, 373, 1879310336, 8513377, -520089437, 33039, 30912640, -2144730723, 122882, -2054879225, -2004575864, 1267073794, 1232000975, -1209806339, -142633741, -2124481665, 1257813535, 1853382398, -1459618273, -385879762, 267826162, -281960608, …]
[[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(916168) [26, 69, 223, 163, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 66, 134
```

I think this what causing the issue !

3- this is my error log on chrome :

```
Timestamp   Property    Value
00:00:00.000    origin_url  http://e-learning.local/
00:00:00.000    frame_url   http://e-learning.local/test
00:00:00.000    frame_title 
00:00:00.000    surface_layer_mode  kOnDemand
00:00:00.000    url blob:http://e-learning.local/86e00165-f1f1-4aec-be2e-a1f9d3171519
00:00:00.000    info    ChunkDemuxer: buffering by DTS
00:00:00.000    pipeline_state  kStarting
00:00:00.084    found_video_stream  true
00:00:00.084    video_codec_name    vp8
00:00:00.084    found_audio_stream  true
00:00:00.084    audio_codec_name    opus
00:00:00.084    error   Got a block with a timecode before the previous block.
00:00:00.084    error   Append: stream parsing failed. Data size=131072 append_window_start=0 append_window_end=inf
00:00:00.085    audio_dds   false
00:00:00.085    audio_decoder   FFmpegAudioDecoder
00:00:00.085    is_platform_audio_decoder   false
00:00:00.085    info    Selected FFmpegAudioDecoder for audio decoding, config: codec: opus, bytes_per_channel: 4, channel_layout: 2, channels: 1, samples_per_second: 48000, sample_format: 4, bytes_per_frame: 4, seek_preroll: 80000us, codec_delay: 312, has extra data: true, encryption scheme: Unencrypted, discard decoder delay: true
00:00:00.086    video_dds   false
00:00:00.086    video_decoder   FFmpegVideoDecoder
00:00:00.086    is_platform_video_decoder   false
00:00:00.086    info    Selected FFmpegVideoDecoder for video decoding, config: codec: vp8, format: PIXEL_FORMAT_I420, profile: vp8, coded size: [640,480], visible rect: [0,0,640,480], natural size: [640,480], has extra data: false, encryption scheme: Unencrypted, rotation: 0°
00:00:00.086    pipeline_state  kPlaying
00:00:00.086    audio_buffering_state   BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
00:00:00.086    video_buffering_state   BUFFERING_HAVE_ENOUGH
00:00:00.089    pipeline_error  CHUNK_DEMUXER_ERROR_APPEND_FAILED
00:00:00.089    pipeline_state  kStopping
00:00:00.099    pipeline_state  kStopped
00:00:00.084    duration    unknown
```

I think firefox generate negative timecode while recording, but chrome refuse to read the video if it has negative timecode !

I also tried to use native `MediaRecorder` API, but firefox still generate a negative value and chrome refuse to add it to video sourceBuffer.

Comment: Most likely the videos actually have independet timestamps. You have not published the video files, but from the javascript code it seems that you are downloading separate independent video files, which most likely all have their timestamps starting at 0, thus the error.

Comment: The implementation of `MediaSource` at Chromium/Chrome and Firefox is different. Can you reproduce the issue at stacksnippets or plnkr https://plnkr.co?